# How to send text from cmd prompt to vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to correctly output text to a file using cmd?

```
code HelloWorld Debug.js
```

It does open three new tabs:
`cli.js` `HelloWorld` `Debug.js`

I'm trying to output `HelloWorld` inside of `Debug.js`

Also, how to stop it from opening this `cli.js` window each time?

Comment: in windows you can use `echo hello world >> file.js`

Comment: what is `HelloWorld`

Comment: The text im trying to append inside the file Debug.js?

Comment: why would that be possible with the CLI of an editor?

Comment: Is not possible to open a new tab in the vscode with a given text using the prompt?

Comment: @rioV8 could you answer?

Comment: have you looked at the CLI options of VSC, if not one of them does what you want most likely VSC can't do it